# Accessing parent properties from processStrategy

Tags: normalizr

I have the following schema:

```
const dataPointSchema = new schema.Entity(
  DATA_POINT_ENTITY_TYPE,
  undefined,
  {
    processStrategy: (value, parent) => {
      console.log({parent});
      return value;
    }
  }
);
const dataPointsSchema = new schema.Array(dataPointSchema);
const dataRowSchema = new schema.Entity(
  DATA_ROW_ENTITY_TYPE,
  {_embedded: {'data-points': dataPointsSchema}}
);

const dataRowsSchema = new schema.Array(dataRowSchema);

return normalize(dataRows, dataRowsSchema);
```

I am expecting the `parent` printed out when I `normalize` to have all the properties of the `data-row`, but instead it only shows the `data-points` that I have told it about in the `dataRowSchema`. Is this a bug or is this the expected behavior?

It looks like what is happening is that `_embedded` is what comes in as the parent in the `dataPointSchema` process strategy. A working example is as follows:

```
import {normalize, schema} from 'normalizr';

const someDataRows = [
{
  _embedded: {'data-points': [{id: 'Uv2k4uW_-6xzh8ImYNwh-0'}]},
  id: 'Uv2k4uW_-6xzh8ImYNwh',
  blah: 'hello'
},
{
  _embedded: {'data-points': [{id: '-B0jeFmCROeL5ICJpx-b'}]},
  id: 'D01A08',
  blah: 'hello1'
}
];

function normalizeRows(dataRows) {
  const dataPointSchema = new schema.Entity(
    'data-point',
    undefined,
    {
      processStrategy: (value, parent) => {
        console.log({parent});
        return value;
      }
    }
  );
  const dataPointsSchema = new schema.Array(dataPointSchema);
  const dataRowSchema = new schema.Entity(
    'data-row',
    {_embedded: {'data-points': dataPointsSchema}}
  );

  const dataRowsSchema = new schema.Array(dataRowSchema);

  return normalize(dataRows, dataRowsSchema);
}

normalizeRows(someDataRows);
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you provide a working example that can be copy/pasted into a node terminal? What version of normalizr are you using?

Comment: Greatly appreciate the response. I've updated with a working example and further findings. We're using the latest version of normalizr (v3.2.4).

Comment: Worthy of noting -- if I change my data model to drop the `_embedded` wrapper and reflect those changes in the `dataRowSchema` definition, then all the parent properties come through properly on the `dataPointSchema` process strategy. Are we using the `dataRowSchema` definition wrong? `dataPointSchema` seems to think the `_embedded` object is its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. The `parent` is the parent object, which happens to be the value of `_embedded`. Technically speaking, plain objects are a type of non-unique schema. This could be rewritten without shorthand so it makes more sense:

```
const dataRowSchema = new schema.Entity(
    'data-row',
    {_embedded: new schema.Object({'data-points': dataPointsSchema}})
);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the input!